# Process pasued but connection not terminated to files in locasystem

Tags: command-line, bash, process

I am not sure whether this is the right place or not but as this is a question which needed a solution I am posting here.

I have used

`kill -SIGSTOP 1234`

command to pasue a process named as `1234` and its paused then I did like

`echo "" > mylogfile.log`

and its size right now like `1byte`, so its worked. Then I again started that paused process with

`kill -SIGCONT 1234`

and given `ls -sh` but I dont know how `mylogfile.log` showing old size and not  new updated size as 1byte.

**So what I am trying to achieve ?**

Simple , I dont want to kill the process to nullify my logfile. when I did `SIGSTOP` process running but my log file went to `0 bytes` and when I start it with `SIGCONT` and its GB size back but I dont want this GB size. I want to have my logfile as `0 byte only`

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Please help and I am sure this will help lot of System Administrators.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems the file `mylogfile.log` is a `sparse` file, its actually a preallocation of empty disk blocks..it should not use any block on disk..check with `du mylogfile.log` ..

Answer (score 1):

`SIGSTOP` pauses a process without the processes' knowledge or consent. The process knows that the next byte it wants to write to one of its opened files is at GB+1. `SIGSTOP/SIGCONT` does not adjust this position information.

The usual way to handle this problem is catching a `SIGHUP` **in the program** and reopening the log, then contuning.